# JBoss 7.1 standalone/tmp/vfs steadily growing

Tags: java, jboss

I'm using JBoss 7.1 and see that the standalone/tmp/vfs directory is steadily growing and that will eventually lead to out of disk space problems. I can of course manually clean up and restart the app, but that is not a stable situation.
Is there permanent fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

I also encounter such a problem in JBoss 7.1.1 [issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-925).
I have updated and It works fine in WildFly CR8.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

This came up several times with Jboss 7.1, and it was fixed in later releases, and is fixed in Wildfly 8 so the recommended solution will be to upgrade.

As a workaround, the 'tmp' directory can safely be deleted during shutdown of the server, for instance in the init-script.

This has also been the recommended workaround for older versions of EAP6 before it was fixed (in 6.2 I believe): [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=901210)